# Submitting a cshtml form using ajax

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, ajax

```
@{
var db = Database.Open("CMS");

//retrieving the username of the user from the session
var session_username = Session["session_username"];

//get the details of the user from the database
var getuserdetailscommand = "SELECT * from student where student_username = @0";
var getuserdetailsdata = db.Query(getuserdetailscommand, session_username);

var statusfirstname = "";
var statuslastname = "";
var statusavatar = "";

foreach(var row in getuserdetailsdata){
    statusfirstname = row.student_firstname;
    statuslastname = row.student_lastname;
    statusavatar = row.student_avatar;
}

//on submit execute the following queries
if(IsPost){
    if(Request["button"] == "sharestatus"){
        //retrieve the data from the form input fields
        var statusbody = Request.Form["statusbody"];
        var statususername = session_username;

        //insert the status for the username into the database
        var insertcommand = "INSERT into status(status_body, status_date, status_username, status_firstname, status_lastname, status_avatar) VALUES (@0, @1, @2, @3, @4, @5)";
        db.Execute(insertcommand, statusbody, DateTime.Now, session_username, statusfirstname, statuslastname, statusavatar);
    }
}
}
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        function get() {
        $.post('statusupdateform.cshtml', { name: form.name.value }
    }
</script>

                                        <form class="status-form" role="form" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" name="form">
                                            <div class="form-body">
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="What's on your mind?" name="statusbody"></textarea>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-footer">
                                                <div class="pull-right actions">
                                                    <button class="btn btn-primary" name="button" value="sharestatus" onclick="event.preventDefault();get();return false;">Share</button>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </form>
```

This is the code in my cshtml file. I want to submit the form using ajax so that the whole page doesn't get refreshed everytime a user submits anything.

The C# code necessary to run the form is also provided in the code.

Any help how can I submit the for using ajax?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use Javascript or JQuery for this. 
E.g. add script tag with link to jquery code file and then use $.get or $.post to make ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove

```
method="post"
```

From the form as this will make the full page submit. Also you can find more information on how to do this in the Jquery documentation.

See the bottom of this link for an example:

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Answer (score 0):

Use This to perform your operations

```
            $.ajax
                ({
                    url: " URL",

                    data: "{ 'name' : 'DATA'}",

                    dataType: "json",

                    type: "POST",

                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",                   

                    async: true,

                    dataFilter: function (data) { return data; },

                    success: function (data) 
                    {
                        alert(data);
                    },
                    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        alert("error");
                    }
                });
```

Comment: I replaced this code `<script type="text/javascript">
        function get() {
        $.post('statusupdateform.cshtml', { name: form.name.value }
    }
</script>` with the above code and it shows 'error'.

Comment: try to use mine code then  it will not return the error

Comment: This doesn't do the submission in an ajax way. It refreshes the whole page.